# How to join 2 dataframes and pivot them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to join 2 dataframes and pivot them

I have this **dfICU** dataframe that has list of *ICU* units in a hospital

```
ICU
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2Closed
B2Covid
B7
C1West
C2South
C3
.
.
.
P53Child
```

the other dataframe **dfPts** has Patients info

```
PtsID  VisitID   ICU        Frequency
934    15        A3         4
934    15        C2South    2
934    62       B2Covid    5
934    62        A2         6
882    35        C2South    7
882    35        C3         2
882    35        A2         9
882    91        P53Child   5
105    44        C2South    2
105    80        B7         8
```

I am trying to put them both in a single pivoted dataframe so if the ICU unit does not exit in the **dfPts** it shows 0 Frequency

Something like this

```
PtsID  VisitID   A1   A2   A3    B1   B2Closed   B2Covid   B7   C1West   C2South   C3   ....  P53Child
934    15        0    0    4     0    0          0         0    0        2         0          0
934    62        0    6    0     0    0          5         0    0        0         0          0
882    35        0    0    0     0    0          0         0    0        7         2          0
882    91        0    0    0     0    0          0         0    0        0         0          5
105    44        0    0    0     0    0          0         0    0        2         0          0
105    80        0    0    0     0    0          0         8    0        0         0          0
```

I start by pivoting the dfPts but that did not add all ICU units in **dfICU** because some *ICUs* are *0* for all patients

here is what i have done so far and did not know what to do after

```
df = dfPts.set_index(['PtsID','VisitID']).pivot(columns='ICU')['Frequency']
df[np.isnan(df)] = 0
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot the dataframe then reindex to ensure all the icus are present in the column headers, then fill the values in missing icus with 0

```
icus = dfICU['ICU'].unique()
(
    dfPts
    .pivot(index=['PtsID', 'VisitID'], columns='ICU', values='Frequency')
    .reindex(columns=icus)
    .fillna(0).reset_index()
)
```

Result

```
ICU  PtsID  VisitID   A1   A2   A3   B1  B2Closed  B2Covid   B7  C1West  C2South   C3  P53Child
0      105       44  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0       0.0      0.0  0.0     0.0      2.0  0.0       0.0
1      105       80  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0       0.0      0.0  8.0     0.0      0.0  0.0       0.0
2      882       35  0.0  9.0  0.0  0.0       0.0      0.0  0.0     0.0      7.0  2.0       0.0
3      882       91  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0       0.0      0.0  0.0     0.0      0.0  0.0       5.0
4      934       15  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0       0.0      0.0  0.0     0.0      2.0  0.0       0.0
5      934       62  0.0  6.0  0.0  0.0       0.0      5.0  0.0     0.0      0.0  0.0       0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `dfICU` only contains a list of values that are already present in the column `ICU` in `dfPts`, you only need to use `dfPts` for the pivot table you want.

Before creating the pivot table, make sure `Frequency` is numeric:

```
# get info of columns
dfPts.info()
```

Then create pivot table:

```
# create a pivot table
pivot_table = (pd.pivot_table(dfPts, index=['PtsID','VisitID'], 
               columns='ICU', values='Frequency',
               aggfunc='sum') # you can change the aggregation function 
               #.reset_index() # uncomment if you want indices as columns 
               )

# check pivot table
pivot_table.head(10)
```

If you find that some ICUs from `dfICU` are missing in the pivot table columns, you can add them with 0 values like this:

```
# create list of missing columns
ICU_list = list(dfICU.ICU.unique())
missing_cols = [col for col in ICU_list 
                if col not in pivot_table.columns]

# add missing columns to pivot table
for col in missing_cols:
    pivot_table[col] = 0

# check pivot table
pivot_table.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
(pd.concat([dfPts, dfICU])
 .pivot(index=['PtsID', 'VisitID'], columns='ICU', values='Frequency')
 .dropna(how='all').reset_index().fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
ICU  PtsID  VisitID   A1   A2   A3   B1  B2Closed  B2Covid   B7  C1West  \
0    105.0     44.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0       0.0      0.0  0.0     0.0   
1    105.0     80.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0       0.0      0.0  8.0     0.0   
2    882.0     35.0  0.0  9.0  0.0  0.0       0.0      0.0  0.0     0.0   
3    882.0     91.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0       0.0      0.0  0.0     0.0   
4    934.0     15.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0       0.0      0.0  0.0     0.0   
5    934.0     62.0  0.0  6.0  0.0  0.0       0.0      5.0  0.0     0.0   

ICU  C2South   C3  P53Child  
0        2.0  0.0       0.0  
1        0.0  0.0       0.0  
2        7.0  2.0       0.0  
3        0.0  0.0       5.0  
4        2.0  0.0       0.0  
5        0.0  0.0       0.0
```